# PHP: Using $_SESSION['SESSION_NAME'] with array ex. $_SESSION['rank']['power']

Tags: php, arrays, session

`Using $_SESSION['Session_Name']['Session_Array']`

`$_SESSION` is basically an array which is getting `stored` as an `global` array, so would it be possible to assign an array into a session?

I am working with a ranking system which needs it quite a lot.
Here is the file structure I am using to test this out: (PHP TAGS ARE INCLUDED BUT NOT SHOWN IN SCRIPT)

index.php

---

```
session_start();
include 'testsessions.php';
include 'ranks.php';
include 'errorchecking.php';
```

ranks.php

---

```
$ranks = [
    /* Global rankname => Rank prefix */
    'Owner'         => '[Owner]', // + Developers
    'Co-Owner'      => '[Co-Owner]',
    'Administrator' => '[Admin]',
    'Moderator'     => '[Mod]',
    'Spy'           => '[Default]',
    'Default'       => '[Default]',
    'Not_logged_in' => '(Guest)'
];



if($_SESSION['rank'] === $ranks['Owner']){
    $_SESSION['rank'] = [
        /* Permission node => setting */
        'power' => 9999, // This is the first thing the error system will check, and also the "strenght" of the group, like how much the group have permission to.
        'has_click' => array($buttons['all'], $links['public'], $links['chat'], $links['forum'], $navigation['all']),
        'has_kick_power' => 'max'
        //etc
    ];
}
echo $_SESSION['rank']['has_kick_power']; // This will work normal, keep reading and you will see the error.
```

> For now I do not care about SQL Injection, I already have that covered in my files.

testsessions.php

---

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = '0'; // Unique_ID
$_SESSION['First_Name'] = 'Fname';
$_SESSION['Last_Name'] = 'Lname';
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Admin';     $username = $_SESSION['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = 'changeme';  $password = $_SESSION['password'];  encrypt($password);   // encrypt() is a function I've made for hashing..
$_SESSION['loginkey'] = "$username$password";
$_SESSION['rank'] = 'Owner';
$_SESSION['active'] = 'Always';
```

errorchecking.php  |  There is errors in this file:

> ' **Warning:** Illegal string offset 'power' in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php/(file_name).php on line (line_number)**'

```
if($_SESSION['rank']['power'] < 30){
    echo 'Sorry, your rank power is too low to view this page!';
    // And also now I am only using ECHO for testing, my system is better then that :)
// Including that it still says 'Sorry, your rank power is too low to view this page!' even though the Owner's rank power is 9999.. I think that is because of the error?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can sure pretty much stuff anything into the session.

As for your warning it's because the key 'power' does not exist.

It's good practice to always check if a key exists before accessing it using the 'isset' function.

For example:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['rank']['power']) && $_SESSION['rank']['power'] < 30){
etc..
```

**UPDATE**

As for the specific warning, since $_SESSION['rank'] is a string, you cannot treat it like an array.

Comment: The keys do exist, I am doing it the exact same way in my files, but it is just an "Illigal"string or something wich i do not understand..

Comment: I see, so it might not be in "contact" with an array?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: Is there some other way I can do it in?

Comment: You have several issues with your code. Use a 'top level' array that holds all your data. Use isset everywhere. Test at every point to make sure your logic works.

Comment: Okay, I'll do so but I have to go now